# Matlab imshow, montage don't work on x64 but do on x86

Tags: matlab, image-processing

I have 2 machines, one running x86 Ubuntu Precise, the another one is x64. I installed MATLAB to both of them. The same version, same license file, only different architecture of MATLAB. Image Processing Toolbox has been installed to both, the same version. On x86 box everything works fine, but on the x64 box some functions of Image Processing Toolbox don't work at all, for example montage, imshow, etc. Here is the output of ver command:

```
MATLAB Version 7.13.0.564 (R2011b)
MATLAB License Number: 659101
Operating System: Linux 3.2.0-30-generic #48-Ubuntu SMP Fri Aug 24 16:52:48 UTC 2012  x86_64
Java VM Version: Java 1.6.0_17-b04 with Sun Microsystems Inc. Java HotSpot(TM) 64-Bit Server VM mixed mode
-------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
MATLAB                                                Version 7.13       (R2011b)  
Simulink                                              Version 7.8        (R2011b)
Communications System Toolbox                         Version 5.1        (R2011b)
Control System Toolbox                                Version 9.2        (R2011b)
Curve Fitting Toolbox                                 Version 3.2        (R2011b)
DSP System Toolbox                                    Version 8.1        (R2011b)
Fixed-Point Toolbox                                   Version 3.4        (R2011b)
Image Processing Toolbox                              Version 7.3        (R2011b)
Neural Network Toolbox                                Version 7.0.2      (R2011b)
Signal Processing Toolbox                             Version 6.16       (R2011b)
SimPowerSystems                                       Version 5.5        (R2011b)
Simscape                                              Version 3.6        (R2011b)
Statistics Toolbox                                    Version 7.6        (R2011b)
Symbolic Math Toolbox                                 Version 5.7        (R2011b)
System Identification Toolbox                         Version 7.4.3      (R2011b)
Wavelet Toolbox                                       Version 4.8        (R2011b)
```

If i try to run imshow, I'm getting this:

```
>> imshow x
Undefined function or variable 'imshow'.
```

Nevertheless, when I write imsh... and press tab, Matlab seems to know the function. I'm confused.

I have been trying to solve this issue for nearly two days and I'm desperate now. I need the functions working, I can't do my homework otherwise. Any hint is welcome.

Comment: What does 'which imshow' return on the two machines? Have you tried searching for imshow.m in each of the Matlab root directories? What are you Matlab command-line strings (-nojvm may be a problem)?

Comment: Thaks for a hint. I tried it and I'm getting this:
    /...../matlab/toolbox/images/imuitools/imshow.m  % Has no license available
On the machine where it doesn't work. On the machine where it does, the "No license" note is not present. Weird though. I'm using the same license file.

Comment: Is it a network licence or a standalone licence for each machine? If the latter, maybe it would help to login to Mathworks and download/install the x64 licence again (standalone licences are specific to your generated machine host ID)

Comment: It's a network license. I will go ask the guy responsible for Matlab licenses in my institution. Perhaps they only have x86 floating licenses available for the given toolbox? Well at least I know it's license-related. Thanks a lot!

Comment: No problem, would be interested to know the outcome. Have only ever had problems with a network licence when the major version numbers differed, e.g. if the 32-bit install was not also R2011b.